# Phonegap GPS in offline mode

Tags: gps, cordova

I'm creating a quick very simple mobile app using phone gap.

One of the APIs I'm hooking into is the gps.  For some reason, the gps is not working while the device has no wifi or cell connection.  I'm testing on a nexus10 which should have a gps receiver.

Is there anyway to force the device to use the gps receiver or is a connection a requirement to the GPS API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });`

"enableHighAccuracy" tells the Android device to use the GPS receiver rather than rely on Wifi or cell triangulation. An internet connection isn't required to use the GPS receiver.